# Thunderbolt 3 compatible with Apple Thunderbolt Display

Tags: mac, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

Is it possible to connect a Thunderbolt 3 equipped Mac (I know there isn't one at present) with the 2011 Apple Thunderbolt Display?
I'm just curious. Maybe there's an adapter which works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Thunderbolt 3 [FAQ](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/tech/faq), it states the following which should apply to all Thunderbolt-labeled Display Port displays.

> Thunderbolt 3 ports are fully compatible with DisplayPort devices and cables.

and

> Products built to Thunderbolt and Thunderbolt 2 specifications will work with Thunderbolt 3 via an adapter.

Comment: I also read this on the Thunderbold Intel homepage. I hope the adapter works with the Apple Thunderbolt Display also.

Comment: Yet this is just an educated guess.